# Apply background color to text region only

Tags: sublimetext3, textmate

In my theme, I've set the background color for comments. But the color is applied to the entire row, rather than just the area with text. Is there a theme setting I can use to fix that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Sublime Text theme engine relies on the scopes defined in the language syntax.
Executing `view.scope_name(view.sel()[0].begin())` in the Sublime Console when the cursor is inside the comment shows `source.python string.quoted.double.block.python` - and is the same when the cursor is in a whitespace section of the string and when it isn't.
This means you would need to alter the python language definition that Sublime uses to report a different scope when relevant, for example, `string.quoted.double.block.whitespace.python`, before you can use it in your theme.

Comment: I believe this newline `<string>(#).*$\n?</string>` is the problem. Yea, removing the newline seems to have outright fixed it.